# How to add a custom svg shape in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a chart for airline incidents, and I want to replace the circle shape with a plane shape.
I've made a pretty simple plane SVG and can't figure out how to use it in my chart. I appreciate any help you can provide.
This is the SVG I'd like to use:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="313" height="305">
<path d="m2,106h28l24,30h72l-44,-133h35l80,132h98c21,0 21,34 0,34l-98,0 -80,134h-35l43,-133h-71l-24,30h-28l15,-47"/>
</svg>
```

This is the code for the chart:
I tried to give a path parameter to the SVG in the append method, but it didn't work.

```
    <!-- Code from d3-graph-gallery.com -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>


<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 90, left: 40},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Parse the Data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/7_OneCatOneNum_header.csv", function(data) {

// X axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Country; }))
  .padding(1);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

// Add Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 13000])
  .range([ height, 0]);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Lines
svg.selectAll("myline")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.Country); })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.Country); })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d.Value); })
    .attr("y2", y(0))
    .attr("stroke", "grey")

// Circles
svg.selectAll("mycircle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Country); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Value); })
    .attr("r", "4")
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
})

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do more to the transformation of your plane. But this will get you started.

```
var plane_d = "m2,106h28l24,30h72l-44,-133h35l80,132h98c21,0 21,34 0,34l-98,0 -80,134h-35l43,-133h-71l-24,30h-28l15,-47"
// Append group for each data point
var planes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return 'translate(' +  x(d.Country) + ',' + y(d.Value) + ')' })

// draw plane on each group
planes.append('path')
    .attr('d', plane_d)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
```